# How to change powershell debugger line color to make it readable

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am having a problem to read PowerShell debugger line.

Please check line 5. it's much darker in life to the point I can't determine what is the code there.

Is there a way to change the background color to yellow or something else so text is readable?

I checked `Tools-->Options-->Script` Pane but could not find options for Debugging.
`Tools-->Options-->Console Pane-->Debug` Background address options for Console Windows - Not what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: See [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/08/21/exploring-the-windows-powershell-ise-color-objects/) and check `$psISE.Options.PSobject.properties|? name -like 'Debug*'`

Comment: I would suggest you to start suing VSCode
https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score -1):

I changed the Tools --> Options --> Script Pane --> Script Pane Tokens --> Variable
color to Light Coral and that seemed to do the trick for me!

Comment: So you can't change the debugger background color?